# Building OpenBlas with msys2

Tags: c++, gcc, openblas, msys2

I have a windows 7-64bit computer and I am trying to build OpenBlas library through Msys2.

There seems to be some problem with the gcc as after installing minGW and unziped OpenBlas folder, I open msys2 and I navigate to the folder where OpenBlas is located. I type the command make and I get this error:

make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [getarch] Error 127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See our PKGBUILD for openblas:
https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-openblas/PKGBUILD#L33